# wordpress archive a user

Tags: php, users, archives

*Please note this question was originally created in stack overflow. I have moved it here due to recommendation.*

I apologize if this can be answered elsewhere. I tried searching around with no answers. This may be due to my choice or words for searching or lack of understanding with WordPress.

I am a developer, but rather new to WordPress (and PHP in general). one of the dev's has left who maintained the WordPress sites so I am now trying to add amendments without having someone in the office for additional guidance.

**our client has asked for a feature to auto-archive users who have not logged in for 4 months**. I am sure this is possible by adding additional columns and PHP code to verify login, but I would like to know a "good" way of implementing this. Is there a recommended add-on?

I see answers about archiving pages/posts, but would like to archive at user level. I have noticed a column named user_status in the wp_users table but does not appear to be used.

*The "auto" part to the question I am not concerned about here. Should be able to achieve this with a simple daily Cron job.*

Any suggestion and/or pointers would be appreciated. Any further queries, I will reply back as soon as I can.

**edit 1 --**
I need to be able to archive a user so they cannot login anymore. Every website I have created that includes a user also contains an archive (or isActive) flag. So having an option to archive at user level has always been a no-brainer for me. For wordpress not have this option by default puzzles me (again, as mentioned above, may be due to my lack of search terms or lack of wordpress knowledge in general)

Despite being able to archive a user so they cannot login, they should still be listed in the admin section (say if the archive flag is checked, for example)

Just trying to get my head round an 'efficient' way of adding this.
**---------**

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean exactly wth "archive"? Archived user will not be able anymore to login? Or? They need to be hidden from users list in admin? Is the your a multisite installation?

Comment: Hi G.M. See edit 1